# change jsLayout html template

Tags: magento2, checkout, template, requirejs, static-content

How can i change the jslayout html template to be phtml so i can call other blocks in it?

first i have requirejs-config.js below code

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'SR_DeliveryDate/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'
        }
    }
};
```

and i have checkout_index_index.xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="delivery_date" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">SR_DeliveryDate/js/view/delivery-date-block</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

finally they is rendering js with html template

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'SR_DeliveryDate/delivery-date-block'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var disabled = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.disabled;
            var noday = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.noday;
            var hourMin = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMin);
            var hourMax = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMax);
            var format = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.format;
            if(!format) {
                format = 'yy-mm-dd';
            }
            var disabledDay = disabled.split(",").map(function(item) {
                return parseInt(item, 10);
            });

            ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                    var $el = $(element);
                    //initialize datetimepicker
                    if(noday) {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,
                            hourMin: hourMin,
                            hourMax: hourMax
                        };
                    } else {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,
                            hourMin: hourMin,
                            hourMax: hourMax,
                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var day = date.getDay();
                                if(disabledDay.indexOf(day) > -1) {
                                    return [false];
                                } else {
                                    return [true];
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    $el.datetimepicker(options);

                    var writable = valueAccessor();
                    if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                        var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                        if (propWriters && propWriters.datetimepicker) {
                            writable = propWriters.datetimepicker;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    writable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));
                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                    if (widget) {
                        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        widget.date(date);
                    }
                }
            };

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **no way**

JS Layout in Magento is component based structure where you need to operate with component JS and HTML template file (knockout) for rendering.

I think you may find useful information in [Customize checkout](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/)
 and [JavaScript mixins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html).

Comment: Thanks for your respond @Victor, is it possible to redirect js rendering to a phtml rather than try to force it on JS file but tell JS to redirect everything to phtml file and echo everything there?

Comment: No. But you can do this in another way. You can add any dynamic data from PHP and include result in jsLayout with PHP [Create a plugin for the process method](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/add-checkbox/) and extend your component data with anything. Use this data in your js+template for render. Also you can extend data with [CompositeConfigProvider](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/add-payment-method/#access-the-system-config-data) and access it with `window.checkoutConfig`